# Why is my express Router middleware executing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

Its my first foray into building a REST api with node/express and I have different routes based on resource type (e.g. users, auth, feed). im using express-validator in all the routes, and *some* of the users routes need to be protected with some extra auth middleware. But the additional middleware seems to be executing 10 times instead of once...what am I not understanding here?

**app.js:**

```
const express = require("express");

const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const feedRoutes = require("./routes/feed");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");

var app = express();

app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(feedRoutes);
app.use(userRoutes); //userRoutes contains protected routes

app.use((error, req, res, next) => { //express built in error handler
    //console.log("errorhandler: " + error);
    const status = error.statusCode || 500;
    const message = error.message;
    const data = error.data;
    res.status(status).json({ message: message, data: data });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
...remaining code
```

**routes/user.js:**

```
//user resource related routes
const express = require("express");

//controllers and middlewares
const userController = require("../controllers/user");
const validateInputs = require("../middleware/validateInputs");
const validateAuthTokens = require("../middleware/validateAuthTokens");

//routes that use the controllers
const router = express.Router();

//protect these routes with the validateAuthToken middleware
router.get("/users/:userID/favorites",  validateInputs.getFavoritesValidationRules(), validateAuthTokens, userController.getFavorites);

router.post("/users/:userID/favorites", validateInputs.addFavoriteValidationRules(), validateAuthTokens, userController.addFavorite);

//delete and add have same params and validation rules
router.delete("/users/:userID/favorites", validateInputs.addFavoriteValidationRules(), validateAuthTokens, userController.deleteFavorite);

module.exports = router;
```

**middleware/validateAuthToken.js:**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

    console.log("inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware");
    //remaining auth code
    next();

}
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**:

```
server now listening!
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  1
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  2
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  3
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  4
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  5
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  6
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  7
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  8
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  9
inside validateAuthTokenMiddleware  10
```

Why is the auth validation middleware executing so many times???

Comment: Are you saying that your server receives one incoming request and you get that log entry 10 times?  Which incoming request is it?  It is coming from a browser or from Javascript?

Comment: yes was one request sent through postman that triggered the 10 log entries. I was testing the add favorites endpoint to begin with. In debug mode i see that even after a response is sent to the client (e.g. postman) it loops back to the middleware function again